# How to make absolute text responsive in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a container that is position:relative and in that container I have a container for text that is position:absolute. The reason being, the text is sitting on top of an image. So essentially, the text container is with respect to it's parent container.

However, when I view my page on a mobile device, the image height becomes smaller than the length of the text, and the text doesn't move "up" with the image. So essentially I can't see the bottom text because image height doesn't cover all the text.

I thought that since the text is relative to that image container, the height of the image will be maintained to a point, so that all the text will appear to have the image under it.

Can anyone help me out with this?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" style="position: relative;"><img src="images/house.jpg" style="width: 100%;" />
        <div class="text" style="position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 10px;">
            <h1>Top Text of List</h1>
            <h3>List1</h3>
            <h3>List2</h3>
            <h3>List3</h3>
            <h3>List4</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle is here, https://jsfiddle.net/y2xjLz5b/

Comment: Please, provide jsfiddle

Comment: Here it is, https://jsfiddle.net/y2xjLz5b/

Comment: why should the text be pulled up? you can do it with media queries.

Comment: I thought it would be because it is sitting inside the parent container? I don't know anything about media queries, how would I use that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is happening because the image has styling setting it's width to 100% ('width: 100%;') - this means that the image width will stretch/shrink to fit it's container, ".col-md-12". So when '.col-md-12' gets small on a mobile device, the image is shrunk down so that it's width is the same as the width of '.col-md-12', and because the image will shrink proportionately it's height reduces as well. At this point the height of the image is now smaller than the height of your list container, aka 'div.text".

Depending on what you have access to, there are two pretty simple solutions I can recommend:

1) add a class to that '.col-md-12' container and target that class to make your image it's 'background-image', vs  just having the image as a child element. you will then want to remove the 'position: absolute;' styling on 'div.text' and try instead just adding 10px padding all around '.col-md-12' to achieve the same affect as using 'top: 10px; left: 10px;' when 'div.text' was absolute.

2) use styling to target '.col-md-12' and set that container element equal to the height of it's child 'div.text' (which it would be by default, except that it's child 'div.text' is positioned absolutely, and therefore '.col-md-12' will not automatically have the same height), or 239px. then target the child  and instead of using 'width: 100%;', change the styles to 'height: 100%; width: auto;'.

Comment: no problem!... also, *forgot to add to #1 that you can force the image (once it's a background) to automatically cover the element it's a background of by using the style attribute 'background-size: cover;' on '.col-md-12' if you haven't already done that

Answer (score 0):

You can give the image `min-height` in the css to make sure it won't go below a minimum height needed for the text to be fully presented.